anchor contract interaction with @coral-xyz/anchor transaction not working
I'm Working on a web3 app which is going to interact with an anchor contract on dev net. here's the setup code:
import { IdlAccounts, Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { IDL, Flip } from "./idl";
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const programId = new PublicKey("AucvPcZGZLBkGX61bEonS2A8bPm9CZVVSwgznUWzi6DK"); 

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

export const program = new Program<Flip>(IDL, programId, {
  connection,
});

export const [counterPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from("counter")],
  program.programId
);

export type CounterData = IdlAccounts<Flip>["GameStatus"];

and here;s the IDL:
export const IDL = {
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "coin_flip",
  "instructions": [
      {
          "name": "initialize",
          "accounts": [
              {
                  "name": "gameStatus",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": false
              },
              {
                  "name": "treasury",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": false
              },
              {
                  "name": "player",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": true
              },
              {
                  "name": "systemProgram",
                  "isMut": false,
                  "isSigner": false
              }
          ],
          "args": [
              {
                  "name": "playerData",
                  "type": {
                      "defined": "PlayersDecision"
                  }
              },
              {
                  "name": "amount",
                  "type": "u64"
              },
              {
                  "name": "gameId",
                  "type": "string"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "sendPrize",
          "accounts": [
              {
                  "name": "gameStatus",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": false
              },
              {
                  "name": "winner",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": false
              },
              {
                  "name": "treasury",
                  "isMut": true,
                  "isSigner": true
              },
              {
                  "name": "systemProgram",
                  "isMut": false,
                  "isSigner": false
              }
          ],
          "args": [
              {
                  "name": "gameId",
                  "type": "string"
              }
          ]
      }
  ],
  "accounts": [
      {
          "name": "GameStatus",
          "type": {
              "kind": "struct",
              "fields": [
                  {
                      "name": "player1",
                      "type": {
                          "defined": "PlayersDecision"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "pool",
                      "type": "u64"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "flipResult",
                      "type": {
                          "option": "u64"
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "isClosed",
                      "type": "bool"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  ],
  "types": [
      {
          "name": "RandomNumber",
          "type": {
              "kind": "struct",
              "fields": [
                  {
                      "name": "randomNumber",
                      "type": "u64"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      {
          "name": "PlayersDecision",
          "type": {
              "kind": "struct",
              "fields": [
                  {
                      "name": "player",
                      "type": "publicKey"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "decision",
                      "type": "u64"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  ],
  "errors": [
      {
          "code": 6000,
          "name": "Unauthorized",
          "msg": "Unauthorized access attempt."
      },
      {
          "code": 6001,
          "name": "GameStillActive"
      },
      {
          "code": 6002,
          "name": "NotEnoughFundsToPlay"
      },
      {
          "code": 6003,
          "name": "RandomnessAlreadyRevealed"
      },
      {
          "code": 6004,
          "name": "RandomnessNotResolved"
      },
      {
          "code": 6005,
          "name": "RandomnessExpired"
      },
      {
          "code": 6006,
          "name": "FailedToGetRandomNumber",
          "msg": "Failed to get random number."
      },
      {
          "code": 6007,
          "name": "InvalidDecision",
          "msg": "The decision is invalid."
      },
      {
          "code": 6008,
          "name": "InsufficientBalance"
      },
      {
          "code": 6009,
          "name": "InvalidPlayerData"
      },
      {
          "code": 6010,
          "name": "TransferFailed"
      },
      {
          "code": 6011,
          "name": "AmountZeroNotAllowed"
      },
      {
          "code": 6012,
          "name": "InvalidPlayerDecision",
          "msg": "Decision should be between 0 and 1."
      },
      {
          "code": 6013,
          "name": "CoinAlreadyFlipped"
      },
      {
          "code": 6014,
          "name": "CoinIsNotFlipped"
      },
      {
          "code": 6015,
          "name": "ThePlayerIsNotWinner"
      },
      {
          "code": 6016,
          "name": "WrongWinnerDetermined"
      },
      {
          "code": 6017,
          "name": "GameClosed"
      }
  ]
}

I need to call the "initialize" instruction:
import { useState } from "react";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { program } from "../anchor/setup";

export default function Initialize() {
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const onClick = async () => {
    if (!publicKey) return;

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      // Create a transaction to invoke the function 
      const transaction = await program.methods
        .initialize()
        .transaction();

      const transactionSignature = await sendTransaction(
        transaction,
        connection
      );

      console.log(`View on explorer: https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-alpha`);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="w-24"
        onClick={onClick}
        disabled={!publicKey}
      >
        {isLoading ? "Loading" : "Initialize"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}


but get this error:
Error: This function requires the Provider interface implementor to have a 'wallet' field.
    at _AccountsResolver.resolveConst (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=111e60b1:10457:17)
    at _AccountsResolver.resolve (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=111e60b1:10381:16)
    at MethodsBuilder.transaction (@coral-xyz_anchor.js?v=111e60b1:10906:36)
    at onClick (increment-button.jsx:19:10)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:3674:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:3699:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:3733:39)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:3736:33)
    at executeDispatch (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:7016:11)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (chunk-2HGVQE7Y.js?v=111e60b1:7036:15)

does anyone know where's this error coming from or how to solve it?
I Tried searching for this error but couldn't find anything so far...
